# Were partimenti purely improvisational exercises?

Tags: composition, improvisation

Burney describes Neapolitan conservatory students "pounding out" accompaniment exercises that were full of "jargon and dissonance" in his history of music and Robert Gjerdingen suggests that these exercises were partimenti. Assuming that Gjerdingen is correct, does Burney's statement imply that students did not get the partimento down perfectly at the first go, but rather would have to work at it a bit? If this is the case, would teachers have occasionally had students write out realizations to better understand what they were playing?

Comment: What is the Burney book/article?

Comment: This is the article where I found the reference, but it appears to be an excerpt from Burney's General History of Music.  http://faculty-web.at.northwestern.edu/music/gjerdingen/Papers/PubPapers/18thCentEditorial.pdf

Comment: Related [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/57548/2600).

Comment: it's just pattern exercises, templates that you can then modify for the sake of improv. so you need to practice and memorize them. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nubC3dktQ24

Comment: But the question is if _written realization_ was a part of the teaching. It's already clear performance practice was the basic method.

Comment: @CaydenJohnson, have read the other partiment articles at the main index? http://faculty-web.at.northwestern.edu/music/gjerdingen/Papers/PubPapers/index.htm

Comment: I've read some, but not all of them. Is there a particular one that I look into? It's hard to tell from the titles where to start.

Answer (score 1):

The book "The Art of Partimento" by Sanguinetti contains a history of partimento, and an exposition of the practice, by way of the author's study of the subject, and through direct translations of the original Italian (Venetian) manuscripts on the teaching of partimento. It may have the answers you seek. It is, in my opinion, the best musical text one can find.